# Handling non-Ok requests in dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-http

I have this simple dart snippet:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Client _http = new BrowserClient();

final response = await _http
      .post(url, headers: someHeader, body: someValue);
```

The server for the current request, returns `Bad Request 400` response. I want to be able to get the status code for some reasons. But as soon as the `_http.post` get called, I get this error:

```
POST http://localhost/path 400 (Bad Request)
```

Putting the block in `try/catch` doesn't help, since the exception catched is `ClientException` which has no information about status-code and response-body (which is important here). How can I handle status-codes here, without throwing exceptions?

**UPDATE:**

I have this snippet after `_http.post()` call:

```
if (response.statusCode == 400) {
  //  manage bad request
}
```

But the `response` is `null`, so the `statusCode` is not accessible here.

**UPDATE 2:**
I get the request on server and can trace on server. As I mentioned, the server is sending a `400 Bad Request` response, and works just fine. But getting the response in Dart causes the error.

Comment: What does the error message say ? (XMLHttpRequest error?).  This probably indicates an error creating the request, and not a normal error code from a response.

Comment: This is a `ClientException` error. No useful data.

Answer (score 0):

The `Response` object has a field `statusCode` where you can get the status code of the response.
You can do something like that:

```
final response = await _http
  .post(url, headers: someHeader, body: someValue);
if (response.statusCode == 400) {
  //  manage bad request
}
```

Comment: But this does not work when using the `BrowserClient`, right? As described in the question: you do not get a response but a `ClientException` with no status code or message from the response -> I also reproduced that.

Comment: @Michael is right. There is no `response` at all (`response` is `null` and cant access `statusCode` here

Comment: If you get `ClientException` there is another problem. is your server accessible ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the url, a header or the body is invalid somehow. (e.g. invalid characters in a header). The request is not actually being sent to the server, and so `ClientException` is being thrown instead of giving you a response.

Comment: See the **UPDATE 2** in question pease.

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Perhaps you could post full details on the issue tracker?

https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues

The stack trace from the ClientException and the full details of the post and response will presumably be relevant.